# VertexAi Java SDK is not accepting ServiceAccountKey for authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When I create a Prediction Service Client configured with ServiceAccountKey for the authentication, it fails stating that client is unauthenticated.

```
Exception: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.
```

PS:

I'm able to use the VertexAI console, and Gcloud based auth is working with same account.

I have worked with Bigquery and Pubsub where we use the service account key for authentication and data processing, the clients are working fine without problem but when I try to follow the same suite, the authentication fails in case of VertexAI

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is difficult to diagnose what is going on without seeing how you're trying to initialize the client. If you can show the code, we may be able ot help you further. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)